# react-native: The watchman connection was closed

Tags: ios, react-native, watchman

React-native newbie question here: I can't get it to work on osx. Upon launching 
react-native run-ios testapp my app builds without errors and launches the iphone simulator, in the new terminal 'React Packager' I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  The watchman connection was closed
Error: The watchman connection was closed
    at Client.cancelCommands (/Users/elgerm/react/test3/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:52:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/elgerm/react/test3/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:128:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

In the simulator the app 'testapp' is added but upon launching it, it crashes/stops immediately.

I can't find anything on this in the troubleshooting guide. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to start the react packager again.

do this by:
1) running npm start in your terminal
2) on your device or your emulator look for a 'reloadJS' button and click on it